# Prometheus EKS Cluster monitoring

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, amazon-eks

I have a eks cluster in a public subnet. Prometheus server is running on an ec2 instance in the same subnet. I am unable to find a way to monitor this cluster on prometheus. Are there any configurations I might be missing?
Please suggest what checks I should do.
Could not find any blog/doc that could help resolve my problem.

Comment: can you share your scrape config, so that I can help you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the base64 token which has access to kubernetes api, which you can get it from secrets.
your configuration should look like this, ofcourse the base64 token will be big this is just dummy one.

```
- job_name: ekscluster
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node
    api_server: https://ekscluster.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
    tls_config:
       insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token: "asdaaasdakjfafua09famdn23423sxfsdd3e2342"

  bearer_token: "asdaaasdakjfafua09famdn23423sxfsdd3e2342"
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  relabel_configs:
  - separator: ;
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    replacement: $1
    action: labelmap
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: ekscluster.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
    action: replace
```